# Weighting Vector Dimensions in Mahout

Tags: mahout

Is there a way to weight vector dimensions in Mahout?

I want to build a content based recommender, so am experimenting with building vectors for each item, then running a cosine distance measure. See simple example below.

```
DenseVector a = new DenseVector(new double[] {0.11, 510, 1});
DenseVector b = new DenseVector(new double[] {0.23, 650, 3});

CosineDistanceMeasure cosineDistanceMeasure = new CosineDistanceMeasure();
System.out.println(cosineDistanceMeasure.distance(a, b));
```

However, some vector dimensions are more important than others, so I was wondering how I would go about adding weight to each dimensions.